# Unity: how to tile a texture to be a constant size

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, texture-mapping, uv-mapping, urp

I need to apply a normal map to a mesh so that it remains at the same scale regardless of the size of polygons, I know this should be possible with some complex UV mapping, but I want to use this effect pretty extensively so I would love to have a shader that can do it on the fly. It will only be applied to vertical walls, so it doesn't really need to be able to handle sloped tringles. I am using URP and I know that for lighting to work properly I need to use a modified version of the `simple lit` shader that comes with urp, but despite being the 'simple' shader, it is still way too complicated for me to understand. I imagine this is an issue many game devs encounter so it seems like the should be a pretty simple solution, except I haven't found one. Has anyone else had this issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: I don't think this is a question regarding the UV-mapping but rather how the shader works you are using ...

Comment: @derHugo I added that tag because I thought a potential solution might involve some code to generate UV's with the right proportions

Comment: Yeah I wasn't referring to the tag but in general ;) A UV map is usually static, meaning, it won#t matter if your object is scaled later -> you will rather want to create a shader that ignores the objects scale and use global space based sizing

Comment: I should definitely have been clearer, the vertical walls that this is for will not move, so I was meaning that the UVs could be baked